# XML(in php) parsing on iPhone

Tags: php, iphone, mysql, xml, xml-parsing

I am developing an iPhone app and I want to put some datas to UITableView.
I got an app showing several xml parser run from [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

and then, I'd separated GDataXMLParser from this project and made it run but 
I have an odd problem that I can't figure out.

This is the code putting php file.

```
- (void)start {
    self.startTimeReference = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses];
    self.parsedSongs = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mydomain.blabla/phpxmltest.php"];
    [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(downloadAndParse:) toTarget:self withObject:url];
}
```

When I make a php to xml with echo directly, like this way,

```
......
echo "<entry><title>this is the TEST</title><item>TEST</item></entry>";
......
```

iPhone app does parse this code like XML.
But when I make a php to xml with mySQL query (cause I want to make a xml items from DB), like this way,

```
<?php
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
$result = mysql_connect("localhost", "my ID", "my Password");
mysql_select_db("my DB");
$q = "select name, price, age, likeit, keyword from Table where category=101";
$result = mysql_query($q);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

echo "<entry>\n";
for ($i=1; $i<=$num_rows; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "<item>\n";
    echo "<title>" . $row["name"] . "</title>\n";
    echo "<category>" . $row["price"] . "</category>\n";
    echo "<artist>" . $row["age"] . "</artist>\n";
    echo "<album>" . $row["likeit"] . "</album>\n";
    echo "<releasedate>" . $row["keyword"] . "</releasedate>\n";
    echo "</item>\n";
}
echo "</entry>";
?>
```

iPhone app doesn't parse this code. It tells me there's no item in XML.
What is the most strange to me, is the results on Web Browser are same exactly.
When I put the url in browser, the output itself and the source(with viewing source function of browser) are exactly same. This is the source view in web browser.(Plz don't mind some encoding problem)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entry>
<item>
<title>������ ���ĺ� ������</title>
<category>11000</category>
<artist>3</artist>
<album>0</album>
<releasedate>���ĺ� ���߱�</releasedate>
</item>
<item>
<title>���ĺ� ��������</title>
<category>18000</category>
<artist>3</artist>
<album>0</album>
<releasedate>���ĺ� ����</releasedate>
</item>
…..
```

I've tried hard to make it work but it's too difficult for me. I am a starter in iOS and Web Programming. Please let me know what is the problem and solution. 
Thank u in advance!:D

Comment: Going into depth of your code makes me somewhat confused,so better I show you a quick and easy way for XML parsing in iPhone. [Follow the link](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/),it shows an easy way to move around. Hope that helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I succeeded building XML Parser. What was the problem is When I try to put xml to iPhone XML Parser using php, it doesn't work, especially after extract data from database with php functions. Your recommendation seems good to build XML Parser easily, anyway.

Comment: php function in objective c does not work. Also this code is about how to extract the xml data into objective c. It has nothing to do with php or .net.

Comment: what is this downloadAndParse function? show the code for the same.

Comment: yes, I didn't use php function in objective C also my Xcode Project. I just put url of php file instead of xml file. cause I had to extract some data from web database and put it in xml.

Comment: its not been understood.Also post code for downloadAndParse. Can you be more specific? and try to response soon. I don't have much time then so.

Comment: I used a sample project. This is the link. http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/XMLPerformance.zip

Comment: I edited this project. In this project, there are various XML Parser so I extract GdataXMLParser and made another project with it.

Comment: Sorry, but I think just downloadAndParse code is not enough to make u understand, cause it just call another function. Please see the project I put above comment(below my post).

Comment: why are you forming so difficult coding in your beginning itself? did you follow my link.It is doing the same implementation in simple manner.

Comment: was just because I referred to complex project at the beginning, I think.....T_T

Comment: It is a good thing,I really appreciate it. But what I am telling is that "extract some data from web database and put it in xml" this should be on server side. and also what is this T_T??

Comment: Well, first, I wanted to parse XML, but contents of this should come from database. U can understand if u see my 2nd php code on my post.(with-21-line) U know that we can't access database directly in xml. so I wrote php code to make xml to parse. and then I assigned this php file's url(~.php) instead .xml in objective-c code.

Comment: your last code snippet itself is a XML file and you need to parse data from the same. And for that you will need XML Parser as shown in my link. I don't know why you are making it so difficult while it is not. sorry but my time is up and can't help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> (Plz don't mind some encoding problem)

Maybe we don't mind but the xml parser probably does.
You should

- set the mimetype in the http response header
- set the charset in the http response header (though it's already in the xml declaration)
- set mysql's client encondig to utf8 in order to receive the data utf-8 encoded
- treat all the data from the database with an appropriate escape function
- or even better use something like [XMLWriter](http://docs.php.net/xmlwriter)

and you should also print error messages as a somewhat valid xml document since you told the client that it will receive xml.

E.g. (tested only by `php -l`):

```
<?php
if ( headers_sent() ) {
  die("can't set mimetype and/or charset after output has been sent to the client");
}
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
ini_set('default_mimetype', 'text/xml');
// ini_set('default_mimetype', 'application/xml');

echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';

$mysql = mysql_connect("localhost", "my ID", "my Password");
if ( !$mysql ) {
    die('<error>database connection failed</error>');
}

if ( !mysql_select_db("my DB", $mysql) ) {
    die('<error>database selection failed</error>');
}

if ( !mysql_set_charset('utf8', $mysql) ) {
    die('<error>setting database selectiocharset failed</error>');
}

$q = 'SELECT name, price, age, likeit, keyword FROM Table WHERE category=101';
$result = mysql_query($q, $mysql);
if ( !$result ) {
    die('<error>database query failed</error>');
}


echo "<entry>\n";
while( false!=($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) ) {
    echo '
        <item>
            <title>',  htmlspecialchars($row["name"], 'utf-8'), '</title>
            <category>', htmlspecialchars($row["price"], 'utf-8'), '</category>
            <artist>', htmlspecialchars($row["age"], 'utf-8'), '</artist>
            <album>', htmlspecialchars($row["likeit"], 'utf-8'), '"</album>
            <releasedate>',  htmlspecialchars($row["keyword"], 'utf-8'), '</releasedate>
        </item>';
}
echo "</entry>";
?>
```

Comment: OMG I don't know how I can appreciate ur help. Actually, I had only a vague idea about those things like http response head, so I wanted to know how I set them. I added 'ini_set' you let me know, so it's working now. Thank you very much!:D & HAPPY NEW YEAR!